# Private iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am interested in writing apps that connect to the intranet or an extranet. In other words, I would like to make private apps for my clients, but I don't want everybody able to access it and be able to download it. **Do you know if there is a way to distribute enterprise apps only to a certain people? Does Android do the same thing?**

Comment: Covered in detail here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [iPhone Enterprise Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/) is targeting exactly this scenario. It allows building and distributing apps outside of the AppStore. It does cost $299 instead of $99, however; and it's available for companies with 500+ employees and Dun&Bradstreet number only. If you are small shop working for big clients, you might want to talk with them enorolling in that program so you can develop the app for them.

**Update:** As @lifeIsGood commented, it looks like Apple has lifted the 500+ employees requirement. At least it's not mentioned anywhere on the Enterprise Developer Program or the [Choose an iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/) comparison page.

They have also added a [Custom B2B Apps](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) distribution mechanism, which seems to target the exact scenario the OP asked about.

Comment: Apparently the 500 employee minimum has been removed.

Comment: Minimum is now 100 employee and it is only to distribute internal company apps, not third party apps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is.... sort of.  You can create ad hoc distribution, but you are limited to 100 total devices in your list.  So, 100 customers.  Or, you can sign up for an enterprise license, but to do so your company must have 500 employees (there may be other restrictions there too).

[edit]
One suggestion might be to create your application as SaaS - and charge for the connection/data store
[/edit]

Comment: Can anyone tell me if this is still true, now that TestFlight has been closed as a way of distributing an app?

Answer (score -2):

I've been looking into this too.  I don't think there's a good way to do this with objective-c, but I do believe this can be done well with HTML5.

I'm reading this book http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/

The iPhone supports the web databases, offline apps, and with the webkit part you get icons so your app can look like a real iphone app and be distributed from a web site.

I don't know much about Android...

Comment: If you find out anything please add the info to your question please.

Comment: By the way I'm using the jqtouch api mentioned in the book.

Comment: I saw that book @ B&N yesterday, nearly bought it.  I'll see how it works on the i'web and buy it if I get some use from it.

Answer (score -3):

For Android, all you do is download the apk file to the phone.  Then you go into Settings > Development and allow Non-market installs.