# What other way can I deploy an iphone app besides AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ip, cordova

Is there another way to deploy a phonegap app?

Thank you!

Comment: Illegally is always an option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone app without AppStore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you join the [Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) ($299/year), you can deploy apps in house.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Appstore is one of the only legal options.  The cydia store for jailbroken phones also can distribute paid and free apps.  If it is a free app, you can always distribute the source code so at least developers can install it.

Comment: Enterprise and AdHoc Distribution are also legal options

Comment: Thats true. Didn't think about that, but without clarification, it can probably be assumed that the OP wants widespread distribution.