# Programming apple iphone/ipad app to communicate with custom electronic device via bluetooth (or WIFI)

Tags: iphone, ipad, mfi

I’m struggling to confirm the following (or believe its this difficult) and wondered if others had already been down this path.

I would like to develop an iPhone/iPad application using Bluetooth that communicates to a custom hardware device using the following Bluetooth module: 
http://www.rovingnetworks.com/products/RN_42_RN42_I_RM

I’ve read about the iAP's but they seem to be for developers who are developing: voice recorders, remote controls and headsets. Using iAP also seems to require using the security co-processor so I would need to integrate that IC on my hardware and join MFI development costs/registration.
http://mfi.apple.com/faqs

However, I just want to send and receive data from aforementioned device thus I should be able to use the native protocols: RFCOMM, SPP or even just the L2CAP without the authentication IC (?) From reading posts on here, they are turned on and the only available protocol is iAP. *Surely Apple hasn’t disabled all native Bluetooth protocols? Or are they enabled with the custom iAP protocols when the authentication IC succeeds?*

If ALL Bluetooth activities on iPhones/iPads require the use of the security coprocessor and use of iAP, *my other option is WIFI where all I need is a developers license ($99) and I can send and receive data to my hardware without MFI?* I.e. there are no Apple based hurdles, assault courses or other such barriers to progress?

So assuming I’ve now got my App and I want to distribute it. 
[iPhone app without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore)

*I presume the problem with the App store is in every case, Apple would want to see an MFI even for the WIFI app because its to communicate with custom hardware?* As a developer distributing apps, I’m limited to 100 clients.

The other option I read is to use the gaming interface but presumably that would incur the wrath of the Apple gods, they wouldn’t let it in the App Store and again I would be stuck to 100 users per developer license.
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502

They don’t make it easy.

Answer (score -1):

it's probably late and you probably got the answer already .... basically Apple would allow "normal" headset/mic connection w/o coprocessor. However, for transferring data, you need it.
However, i understood that, for BLE (i.e from 4S and above) you might not need it, as basically the app includes your profile in it. Still to be confirmed