# How should I install my ios app to devices in the company?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to write app for company where i'm working. 
It will work only with internal resources and only via authentication.
How should staff install this app, when it will be done ? How usually people do that(for example ios soft for restaurants) ? I mean that should they use jailbreak for installing it ? I think that apple won't add my app to repository because it won't have possibility to check it.

Comment: We use MobileIron for our Inhouse App distribution

Comment: Well, one usually plugs his device into the computer and syncs with iTunes...

Comment: Check this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore

Comment: How many people are in your company? Depending on size an MDM may or may not be overkill

Comment: In my company more the 2k but it doesn't matter, this tool will be using only by 10-30 people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two different **official** iPhone [application distribution methods](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/distribute.html) that I am aware of:

**- Ad hoc**

You can distribute applications using ad hoc without going through the app store, but you are limited to a maximum of 100 devices. With this method you can distribute you application from a web site, email, etc. You can upload the app by adding all the devices UDID you want to share the app on provision profile, then generate a link on [testflightapp.com/](http://testflightapp.com/)

**- Enterprise**

The method is for **internal** distribution in companies with more than 500 employees. Apple does not provide any more public detail that I could find on this method.

Comment: Ad hoc is a good way for me but I'll read information about other ways too, I think I should know some info about them.

Comment: I do not believe there is a minimum required to get an enterprise account, only a DUNS number. https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: Biggest time saver I've noticed is not needing to add a new device to the developer portal and needing to recreate a provisioning profile.  By selecting the enterprise profile for the app, you can install it on any device