# Deploy IPhone app only on company's emoyee's phone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone app without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore)

My father is asking me to develop an IPone app for his company so his employees can access a server with all the stock info, etc. and to install it only on the IPhones of the employees. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is enterprise deployment, see this page: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/ - once signed up, you can over-the-air deploy apps to employees of your organisation.