# Common App Store for Android and iOS both privately accessible

Tags: android, ios, app-store

I want to upload my app which is in beta. It is working for both Android and iOS. Initially I want to distribute it privately only to limited user. I know about **Google Play Private Channel** but that is only for Android. I want for both. Is there any store for both which is world wide accessible. And **I dont want to provide UUID** for each Apple user. If not then what other options can be?

Comment: You won't find any solutions that will allow you to work without the UUID, if you could distribute to any device then you would be bypassing Apple's rules. Malware and security issues spring to mind then. It's the way it is for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want one common solution for both iOS and Android, then

1) [Appaloosa](http://www.appaloosa-store.com/?locale=en)

2) [Apphance](http://www.apphance.com/)

3) [TheBetaFamily](http://thebetafamily.com/)

4) [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/)

5) [Bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com/)

6) [AppBlade](https://appblade.com/)

7) [Knappsack](http://knappsack.com/)

8) [Testflight](https://www.testflightapp.com/)

Most of them are paid, but some of them has free trial period.

I am a big fan of Testflight as there service is brilliant and it is free. Unfortunately Testflight only support iOS and there is no chance of that changing since Apple acquired Testflight. If you decided to end up in an iOS only option, then Testflight is the service for you.

Comment: Does Testflight need UUID of device? Because I dont want the store which needs to register user based upon UUID.

Comment: Testflight need UUID... Also, as I have already mentioned Testflight won't work with Android, so I am not sure it suits your needs..

Comment: Is there a way that dont need UUID for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestFlight available here: https://testflightapp.com/

TestFlight can provide over the air download support, feedback, reports etc and is very useful for iOS beta testing

Answer (score 0):

Refer @Krishnabhadra's answer for tools for private beta deployment. For final distribution read this answer:

ios only allows jailbroken phones to install non-app-store apps. So there is no way to put both android and ios apps in the same store/distribution medium as you ask.

ios apps can only be distributed without the app store to a limited audience for testing etc.

You can distribute android apps via your own website or alternate app stores though.

See this thread as well:
[iPhone app without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore)

Comment: OP is not asking for distributing for end users.. He especially saying his app is in beta, so he want to sent to some private users who are his people (I believe)..

Comment: Yes you are right Krishna. I just want to distribute privately for beta release. For final release I will go with Apple app store because I already own Development Program.

Answer (score 0):

You can only distribute iOS apps to unmodified iOS devices if you have registered that device's UDID with Apple in your developer account. This applies to both final store distribution and also any private beta testing. There is no other way.

Thus there is no world accessible solution that meets your wants for native iOS apps.

But you can do HTML5 web apps (clip-able web sites that can run in Safari) that are world accessible without any app approvals.

Comment: My app is developed using Phonegap. Is there a way that dont need UUID for iOS (except Apple's Public App Store)?

Comment: Only if phonegap allows you to put the HTML web app on a web site and run it from there in Safari.